# Connect 4 Winning horizontal function

Tags: c++, algorithm

I implemented this Connect 4 Winning horizontal function but I cannot for the life of me figure out why my c++ horizontal function will not work it is a 2d array

```
for (int j = 0; j < row - 3; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
            
                if (Board[i][j] == charvar && Board[i][j + 1] == charvar && Board[i][j + 2] == charvar && dyBoard[i][j + 3] == charvar) {
                    return charvar;
                }
            
            
        }
    }
```

Wouldnt my array go from [0][0] to [0][1] and so on?  I already tried without the -3 but that dosnt seem to work.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The first array index is row, the second is column, so loops should look like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rowcount; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columncount - 3; j++) {...
```

Comment: @GUUD TRUBES Is my answer unclear or unapplicable?